# Latex rotated multi-column

Tags: tables

[image]Using Latex to try to reproduce the multi-column table with rotation and wrapping of text in the example shown above. It is columns 2 and 3 of the attached image that is giving me the problems.

I've tried a variety things like `\begin{rotate}{90} stuff \end{90}` with no luck.

I've also tried to `\begin{sideways} stuff \end{sideways}` with no luck.

Comment: What about: `\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\rotatecol}[1]{\makebox[1em][l]{\rotatebox{90}{#1}}}`; then in your table: `\rotatecol{Same Research Area}` and `\rotatecol{Support Status}`, etc.  (Sometimes I like to use an angle of 60 degrees for things like these.)  Also: the `1em` will not be enough if your rotated columns need two lines of text.

Comment: Wait: 60 degree angle would be very bad if the other columns are not rotated!  (It is obviously too late for me to be suggesting anything to anyone....)

Comment: Thanks Jon, that only partially works. It is the two lines that make it tricky. I have almost got it with \newcolumntype{P}[2]{%
  >{\begin{turn}{#1}\begin{minipage}{#2}\small\raggedright\hspace{0pt}}l%
  <{\end{minipage}\end{turn}}%
} then by doing \multicolumn{1}{P{90}{4.0cm}@{}}{ \textbf{ Same Research Area} (Yes/No) } but it "covers" up the vertical lines which is no good :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be easier than you think, but it's hard to say since I don't really know the contents of the table.  Anyway, this is a little different from my ad hoc comment, but the principle is the same:

```
\documentclass[landscape]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx,booktabs,longtable}
\newcommand{\sameresearch}{%
  \rotatebox[origin = r]{90}{\parbox[c]{3.5cm}{\hfill\bfs{Same Research Area}\\ \null\hfill (Yes/No)}}}%
\newcommand{\supportstatus}{%
  \rotatebox[origin = r]{90}{\parbox[c]{4cm}{\hfill\bfs{Support Status}\\ (Requested/Current/Past)}}}%

\newcommand{\bfs}[1]{\textsf{\textbf{#1}}}%

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{%
    @{}p{4cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} | p{3cm} |
    p{1cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm}}
  \toprule
  \bfs{Description}\par
  (all named investigators on any Proposal or grant/ project/
  fellowship in which a participant is/was involved, project title,
  source of support, scheme and round) &
  \sameresearch &
  \supportstatus &
  \bfs{Proposal/Project ID} (if applicable) &
  \bfs{2012} (\$'000) &
  \bfs{2013} (\$'000) &
  \bfs{2014} (\$'000) &
  \bfs{2015} (\$'000) &
  \bfs{2016} (\$'000) \\
  \midrule

  &&&&&&&&\\
  &&&&&&&&\\

  \bottomrule
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

I should probably mention that the author of `booktabs`, and much of the `TeX` world, will tell you to avoid vertical rules like the plague.  I would add in a much softer tone that it is bad (English) style to write 'grant/ project/ fellowship': the slash should not have space on one of its sides, though it may take a space on *both* of its sides if one or more of the 'halves' is more than one words long --- e.g., some might think it 'bad / not correct' practice.

Comment: Thank you so much! You can thank the Australian Government for all these vertical rules and bad English/style. I only have to reproduce it for a grant :-)  thanks again.

Comment: @user2172065 -- Yeah, well that's often how it goes: large institutions favour vertical lines in tables.  I guess there are weirder things in life.  Glad it worked out though!