# Aligning rotated headings in LaTeX tables

Tags: tables, pdftex, rotating

I have a wide table that I'm trying to wrangle, and I think I have it just about done except for the table headings. In the example below, I've had to rotate the headings for columns 5, 6, and 8. I've tried any number of things to get those headings to line up (roughly centered) with the non-rotated headings to no avail (e.g., changing the `parbox` optional argument from `c` to `b` to `t` and changing the `multirow` parameters). It looks like the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/210869/how-to-align-rotated-column-headings-in-a-table) could be useful, but I could not make it work; [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102573/latex-rotated-multi-column) did not seem to work either.

Your help is appreciated.

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt, twoside, final, openright, c6paper]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{moresize}
\usepackage{booktabs}                       
\usepackage{multirow}                       
\usepackage{array}                          
\usepackage{hanging}                        
\usepackage{dashrule}                       
\usepackage{longtable}                      
\usepackage{setspace}                       
\usepackage{makecell}                       
\usepackage{colortbl}   
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}     
\usepackage{fancyhdr}       
\usepackage{ragged2e}   
\usepackage{rotating}   
\usepackage{here}       
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, hyperindex=true]{hyperref} 

% COLOR DEFINITION
\definecolor{darkred}{HTML}{AE0000}             
\newcommand{\cdr}{\color{darkred}}

\newcommand{\phz}{\phantom{0}}



\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{60}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}     % Default value: 6pt
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}



\begin{Center}
{\large{festorum mobilium}}
\end{Center}

\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\scriptsize{
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc>{\color{darkred}}c} \toprule \midrule
Anno & \multirow{2}{*}{Ascensio} & \multirow{2}{*}{Pentecostes} & 
Corpus & \raisebox{3em}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}\parbox[c]{16ex}{\centering Indict.}\end{sideways}}} & 
\raisebox{3.4em}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}\parbox[c]{16ex}{\centering Dom.\ post \\ Pentec.}\end{sideways}}} & 
Dom.\ I & \raisebox{3.4em}{\multirow{2}{*}{\begin{sideways}\parbox[c]{16ex}{\centering Litt.\ Mart.}\end{sideways}}} \\
%
Dom. & & & Christi & & & Adventus & \\
%
\midrule
2024 & \phz9 maii & 19 maii & 30 maii & \phz2 & 27 & \phz1 dec. &  u \\
2025 & 29 maii & \phz8 iunii & 19 iunii & \phz3 & 24 & 30 nov. & P \\
2026 & 14 maii & 24 maii & \phz4 iunii & \phz4 & 26 & 29 nov. & l \\
2027 & \phz6 maii & 16 maii & 27 maii & \phz5 & 27 & 28 nov. & C \\
2028 & 25 maii & \phz4 iunii & 15 iunii & \phz6 & 25 & \phz3 dec. & c \\
\midrule
2029 & 10 maii & 20 maii & 31 maii & \phz7 & 27 & \phz2 dec. & p \\
2030 & 30 maii & \phz9 iunii & 20 iunii & \phz8 & 24 & \phz1 dec. & F \\
2031 & 22 maii & \phz1 iunii & 12 iunii & \phz9 & 25 & 30 nov. & f \\
2032 & \phz6 maii & 16 maii & 27 maii & 10 & 27 & 28 nov. & s \\
2033 & 26 maii & \phz5 iunii & 16 iunii & 11 & 24 & 27 nov. & N \\
\midrule 
2034 & 18 maii & 28 maii & \phz8 iunii & 12 & 26 & \phz3 dec. & k \\
2035 & \phz3 maii & 13 maii & 24 maii & 13 & 28 & \phz2 dec. & B \\
2036 & 22 maii & \phz1 iunii & 12 iunii & 14 & 25 & 30 nov. & b \\
2037 & 14 maii & 24 maii & \phz4 iunii & 15 & 26 & 29 nov. & n \\
2038 & \phz3 iunii & 13 iunii & 24 iunii & \phz1 & 23 & 28 nov. & E \\
\midrule
2039 & 19 maii & 29 maii & \phz9 iunii & \phz2 & 25 & 27 nov. & e \\
%
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
}
\end{table}




\end{document}
```

Comment: `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.6}` are you sure you want that? `fontsize=9pt` book doesn't have that option `\large{`, `\scriptsize{`  size commands do not have a `{..}` argument

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably avoid rotating the headings apart from the red one, or rotate them all, but the requested form something like

[image]

```
\documentclass[fontsize=9pt, twoside, final, openright]{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{moresize}
\usepackage{booktabs}                       
\usepackage{array}                          
\usepackage{makecell}                       
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}     
\usepackage{ragged2e}   
\usepackage{graphicx}   
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, hyperindex=true]{hyperref} 

% COLOR DEFINITION
\definecolor{darkred}{HTML}{AE0000}             
\newcommand{\cdr}{\color{darkred}}

\newcommand{\phz}{\phantom{0}}



\begin{document}

\setcounter{page}{60}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}     % Default value: 6pt




\begin{Center}
\large festorum mobilium
\end{Center}

\begin{table}[htp]
\centering
\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{ccccccc>{\color{darkred}}c} \toprule \midrule
\makecell{Anno\\Dom.} &
\makecell{Ascen-\\sio} &
\makecell{Pente-\\costes} & 
\makecell{Corpus\\Christi} & 
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Indict.} & 
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{\makecell{Dom.\ post \\ Pentec.}} & 
\makecell{Dom.\ I\\Adventus} &
\rotatebox[origin=c]{90}{Litt.\ Mart.}\\
%
\midrule
2024 & \phz9 maii & 19 maii & 30 maii & \phz2 & 27 & \phz1 dec. &  u \\
2025 & 29 maii & \phz8 iunii & 19 iunii & \phz3 & 24 & 30 nov. & P \\
2026 & 14 maii & 24 maii & \phz4 iunii & \phz4 & 26 & 29 nov. & l \\
2027 & \phz6 maii & 16 maii & 27 maii & \phz5 & 27 & 28 nov. & C \\
2028 & 25 maii & \phz4 iunii & 15 iunii & \phz6 & 25 & \phz3 dec. & c \\
\midrule
2029 & 10 maii & 20 maii & 31 maii & \phz7 & 27 & \phz2 dec. & p \\
2030 & 30 maii & \phz9 iunii & 20 iunii & \phz8 & 24 & \phz1 dec. & F \\
2031 & 22 maii & \phz1 iunii & 12 iunii & \phz9 & 25 & 30 nov. & f \\
2032 & \phz6 maii & 16 maii & 27 maii & 10 & 27 & 28 nov. & s \\
2033 & 26 maii & \phz5 iunii & 16 iunii & 11 & 24 & 27 nov. & N \\
\midrule 
2034 & 18 maii & 28 maii & \phz8 iunii & 12 & 26 & \phz3 dec. & k \\
2035 & \phz3 maii & 13 maii & 24 maii & 13 & 28 & \phz2 dec. & B \\
2036 & 22 maii & \phz1 iunii & 12 iunii & 14 & 25 & 30 nov. & b \\
2037 & 14 maii & 24 maii & \phz4 iunii & 15 & 26 & 29 nov. & n \\
2038 & \phz3 iunii & 13 iunii & 24 iunii & \phz1 & 23 & 28 nov. & E \\
\midrule
2039 & 19 maii & 29 maii & \phz9 iunii & \phz2 & 25 & 27 nov. & e \\
%
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}




\end{document}
```